# How can you apply two criteria (one dynamic, one static) for same Column in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

For a certain data set, in 'Date' column I want to select dates of previous week (Mon-Sun) and also fields with Blank values. I achieve this manually as seen in below image.

Filter applied in Excel

[image]

I want to automate this filter-ing Process using VBA. But I also don't want to provide static values, because I want to run this code every Monday to filter previous weeks data.

I wrote the below code to filter last calendar week dates:

```
StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) - 7) 
EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) + 0)
Sheets("Processed Data").Range("A3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd,Criteria2:="<" & EndDate
```

But when I add criteria3 for Blank values like below, I get an error.

```
StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) - 7)  
EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) + 0)   
Sheets("Processed Data").Range("A3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & EndDate, Operator:=xlOr, _
    criteria3:="="
```

If I code in below manner, Only fields with Blank values get filtered.

```
StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) - 7)  
EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) + 0) 
Sheets("Processed Data").Range("A3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="<" & EndDate
    
    Sheets("Processed Data").Range("A3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
    Criteria1:="="
```

Is there a way I can solve this issue?

Comment: There is no Criteria3 argument, do the filter for the dates and then, separately, do it for the blanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could record the macro of how you do it manually (in the screenshot) and post the code that you get. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68101937/edit) your post at any time.